# Prepros не компилирует jade

Tags: jade

Доброго времени суток! Когда сохраняю файл index.jade, prepros выдает ошибку (изображение ниже), подскажите как решить эту проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для компиляции Gulp.